# Operation not permitted

Tags: python, linux, ioctl

I want to run some command in python script

```
import fcntl

KDSETLED = 0x4B32
SCR_LED  = 0x01

console_fd = os.open('/dev/console', os.O_NOCTTY)
fcntl.ioctl(console_fd, KDSETLED, SCR_LED)
```

I've set `a+rw` for `/dev/console` but when I run script from regular user:

> fcntl.ioctl(console_fd, KDSETLED,
>   SCR_LED) IOError: [Errno 1] Operation
>   not permitted

What should I do if I need to run that script from regular user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to get your script executed with `CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG`. Either that, or (if you're running on the console), using your controlling tty (e.g., `/dev/tty1`) instead of `/dev/console` might work.

The kernel code that enforces this appears to be drivers/tty/vt/vt_ioctl.c:

```
/*
 * To have permissions to do most of the vt ioctls, we either have
 * to be the owner of the tty, or have CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG.
 */
perm = 0;
if (current->signal->tty == tty || capable(CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG))
    perm = 1;
⋮
case KDSETLED:
    if (!perm)
        goto eperm;
    setledstate(kbd, arg);
    break;
```

So, definitely looks like those are your two options.

Comment: I have the same problem too, changed to /dev/tty7 but don't understand how to ensure user permissions. Couldn't figure out from your pseudo code (?).

Comment: @Alex that's not pseudocode, that's C, part of the Linux kernel sources. You need to either have your code run on the Linux console (not under X), or alternatively have that capability bit set (or be root, which normally has all capability bits set). If you're running under X, you should use the X APIs to change keyboard LEDs. That'd definitely be a different question.

Comment: Upvote, thank you for clarify me that, especially with X. One more stupid question: is it possible to make symbolic link with devices as well ( or something simmilar like #ln -s ~/blahblahdev/console /dev/console)?

Comment: @Alex you can make a symbolic link pointing to any file, including device files. I suggest asking questions about how Unix/Linux work (non-programming questions) on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).